# Can we import the component with different name in React Native

Tags: react-native, import, error-handling, export, importerror

## I have imported the component of Name **StoryBook** that is exported default name.

## But is also works as **StoryBookX**.

e.g

import StoryBook from 'storybook',                 // This is **default name.**
import StoryBookX from 'storybook,                //This is **not default name** but it also work.

Can anybody explain that what the reason of it.

```
<View>
<StoryBook />
</View>



<View>
<StoryBookX />
</View>
```

Both are **wokring** while there is no default component of name **StoryBookX**

## I **tried** it .Because i was expecting that this will not work.But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. if we have a component Like

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
const AdView = () => {
  return <View></View>;
};

export default AdView;
```

then we can export it with different names like this,

```
import AdView from "./AdView"
import CustomAdView from "./AdView"
import MyAdView from "./AdView"
import YourAdView from "./AdView"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you export component as default then you can import it by different name also.